# Unsubscribe Parse Push Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have one android application in which I have used Parse for push notification. I am trying to include notification on/off with settings activity. I have tried for make it working but I am missing something,so unable to mute notification. My Main Activity in which parse code is like below

```
Parse.initialize(this, getString(R.string.parse_application_id), getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
PushService.subscribe(this, "All", MainActivity.class);
```

and in setting activity which have checkbox option for mute notification is like below.

```
notification.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {                 
        if (newValue.equals(true)) {
            PushService.subscribe(getApplicationContext(), "All", MainActivity.class);
        } else {
            PushService.unsubscribe(getApplicationContext(), "All");
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Please check and let me know if there something wrong in my code, because its not working and showing any effect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions here:

1) Subscribe to some channel and you will get notifications from that channel. 
When you uncheck, just unsubscribe and you won't get notifications from that channel.

See more at *SUBSCRIBING TO CHANNELS* : [parse push notifications](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#push-notifications)

2) Some people prefer ignoring messages at broadcast receiver. User won't get notified. (but it's not secure and clean solution)

It means you get push notification on your device, check preference and if you need show user a notification.